# Similar python function of R Vif Function

Tags: python, r, data-science, data-analysis

lately I've been working with both `R` and `Python` for Analytics and Statics studies, so I was wondering what is the similar python function of R `Vif` Function.

Remember that the `Vif` function can help us to find...

The VIF of a predictor is a measure for how easily it is predicted from a linear regression using the other predictors.

Thank you and have all a good day!!

Answer (score 1):

To get vif value in python:

```
from statsmodels.stats.outliers_influence import variance_inflation_factor

variables = lm.model.exog
vif = [variance_inflation_factor(variables, i) for i in 
range(variables.shape[1])]
vif
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge!!